# Html Game - ios Safari Crashing

Tags: javascript, ios, typescript, safari, webgl

I'm running a html app developed using typescript, pixi.js webgl, web audio.

The game runs fine on windows and android across a variety of devices and browsers. However on ios safari we get intermittent crashes on all devices including iphone 4/5/6, ipad 2/mini.

Safari simply gives the error "A problem occured with this web page, so it was reloaded".

When debugging there's no errors or anything suspicious in the console. But I do have some crash logs from the iphone 5 which have the same Exception Type/Sub Type but with different "Global Trace Buffer"'s.

Can anyone help me decipher the log and what might be causing the app to crash on ios?

```
Incident Identifier: EF83BB84-1F13-4BE4-BFFA-F2525156709F
CrashReporter Key:   5b4c4feb75d4a06bac1e8443579e27c43090d8e8
Hardware Model:      iPhone5,2
Process:             com.apple.WebKit.WebContent [259]
Path:                /System/Library/Frameworks/WebKit.framework/XPCServices/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.xpc/com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Identifier:          com.apple.WebKit.WebContent
Version:             8601.1.46.140 (8601)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2016-08-25 15:54:02.02 +0100
Launch Time:         2016-08-25 15:20:53.53 +0100
OS Version:          iOS 9.3.4 (13G35)
Report Version:      105

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Subtype: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0xbbadbeef
Triggered by Thread:  0

Filtered syslog:
None found

Global Trace Buffer (reverse chronological seconds):
1984.610527  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020de09d5 TCP Conn 0x145d7de0 SSL Handshake DONE
1984.744800  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020de090f TCP Conn 0x145d7de0 starting SSL negotiation
1984.745257  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020e60a2d TCP Conn 0x145d7de0 complete. fd: 13, err: 0
1984.746628  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020e61b2f TCP Conn 0x145d7de0 event 1. err: 0
1984.752746  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020e60a2d TCP Conn 0x146d8b10 complete. fd: 12, err: 0
1984.753565  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020e61b2f TCP Conn 0x146d8b10 event 1. err: 0
1984.817849  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020e61bad TCP Conn 0x145d7de0 started
1984.819401  CFNetwork                  0x0000000020e61bad TCP Conn 0x146d8b10 started



Thread 0 name:  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   JavaScriptCore                  0x23d98bcc 0x239db000 + 3922892
1   JavaScriptCore                  0x23d9777a 0x239db000 + 3917690
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x23d95f36 0x239db000 + 3911478
3   JavaScriptCore                  0x239ddbbe 0x239db000 + 11198
4   WebCore                         0x24861160 0x23fac000 + 9130336
5   WebCore                         0x24036e66 0x23fac000 + 568934
6   WebCore                         0x24a2b9ce 0x23fac000 + 11008462
7   WebCore                         0x23fadd08 0x23fac000 + 7432
8   JavaScriptCore                  0x23aa88c2 0x239db000 + 841922
9   ???                             0x5d8c0028 0 + 1569456168
10  ???                             0x5def9532 0 + 1575982386
11  ???                             0x5df0f574 0 + 1576072564
12  ???                             0x5df0e028 0 + 1576067112
13  ???                             0x5dec3a7e 0 + 1575762558
14  ???                             0x5df0cc5e 0 + 1576062046
15  ???                             0x5dfaa5b8 0 + 1576707512
16  ???                             0x5db271a0 0 + 1571975584
17  ???                             0x5df58e28 0 + 1576373800
18  ???                             0x5de48db0 0 + 1575259568
19  ???                             0x5df39520 0 + 1576244512
20  JavaScriptCore                  0x23cd6408 0x239db000 + 3126280
21  ???                             0x5dacd6b8 0 + 1571608248
22  ???                             0x5deabc50 0 + 1575664720
23  ???                             0x5deab1b0 0 + 1575662000
24  ???                             0x5ddd0cd4 0 + 1574767828
25  ???                             0x5deaa296 0 + 1575658134
26  ???                             0x5ddd0c34 0 + 1574767668
27  ???                             0x5d9aae82 0 + 1570418306
28  ???                             0x5dfae9ec 0 + 1576724972
29  ???                             0x5dfce16c 0 + 1576853868
30  ???                             0x5dac4936 0 + 1571572022
31  ???                             0x5df8abd0 0 + 1576578000
32  ???                             0x5dd683dc 0 + 1574339548
33  JavaScriptCore                  0x23cd12b0 0x239db000 + 3105456
34  JavaScriptCore                  0x23c2a1b2 0x239db000 + 2421170
35  JavaScriptCore                  0x23a16da8 0x239db000 + 245160
36  JavaScriptCore                  0x23af3198 0x239db000 + 1147288
37  WebCore                         0x241126e6 0x23fac000 + 1468134
38  WebCore                         0x24112534 0x23fac000 + 1467700
39  WebCore                         0x2463ba10 0x23fac000 + 6879760
40  WebCore                         0x248f0e98 0x23fac000 + 9719448
41  WebCore                         0x2425996a 0x23fac000 + 2808170
42  WebKit                          0x2776b2f2 0x276db000 + 590578
43  WebKit                          0x2772ab98 0x276db000 + 326552
44  WebKit                          0x278487d8 0x276db000 + 1497048
45  WebKit                          0x276f62e2 0x276db000 + 111330
46  WebKit                          0x276f7d06 0x276db000 + 118022
47  JavaScriptCore                  0x23d8842a 0x239db000 + 3855402
48  JavaScriptCore                  0x23d888a2 0x239db000 + 3856546
49  CoreFoundation                  0x2089f9e6 0x207e3000 + 772582
50  CoreFoundation                  0x2089f5d6 0x207e3000 + 771542
51  CoreFoundation                  0x2089d93e 0x207e3000 + 764222
52  CoreFoundation                  0x207ec1c8 0x207e3000 + 37320
53  CoreFoundation                  0x207ebfbc 0x207e3000 + 36796
54  Foundation                      0x2103942c 0x2102e000 + 46124
55  Foundation                      0x21087d74 0x2102e000 + 367988
56  libxpc.dylib                    0x20636048 0x20629000 + 53320
57  libxpc.dylib                    0x2063775c 0x20629000 + 59228
58  com.apple.WebKit.WebContent     0x00036a2c 0x33000 + 14892
```

59  libdyld.dylib                   0x20498872 0x20496000 + 10354

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it's a bug in WebKit. A good start would be to report it to WebKit's tracker: https://webkit.org/reporting-bugs/.

Comment: That doesn't really help figuring out what's causing it to crash.